# Want to display my survey window once in 30 days to each user

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I have code to  display survey popup window on clicking of Submit button , now i want to show the survey only once in every 30 days to each user. Can you please help me in coding to show it once in 30 days, Here is my existing code.

```
        if(document.getElementById("submit")){
            if(jQuery("[name='systemCompanyName']").val() == 'xxxx'){
                document.getElementById("submit").onclick =     function(){
                     var answer = confirm("Please click on OK to take a short survey")
                if(answer)
                window.open(url);

            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: sounds like something you could use `cookies` for. if you set up a cookie that expires 30 days, and then set the program to automatically check if the cookie exists and if not then launch the survey

Answer (score 0):

Call the first if the survey was completed to set a date. And the second to check if nth days were elapsed.

```
function surveyCalled(){

        var data = JSON.stringify({"date":new Date()}) || null;
        localStorage.setItem("survey",data);

}

function checkSurvey(days){

        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("survey")) || {};

            if(data.date){

                if(Math.round((new Date() - new Date(data.date)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) >= days){

                    return true;

                }

          }

      return false;

}


console.log(checkSurvey(10))
```